# Matching on type patterns with type variables and type classes

Tags: scala, generics, pattern-matching, type-inference

This question is still unanswered despite of it was marked as duplicate.

From http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/08-pattern-matching.html#type-patterns we can write following code

Suppose I have a type class:

```
trait T[A] {
  def getType: String
}

object T {
  def apply[A](implicit t: T[A]): T[A] = t

  implicit object TInt extends T[Int] {
    def getType = "Int"
  }
  implicit object TString extends T[String] {
    def getType = "String"
  }
}
```

and typed class which uses my type class

```
class C[A] {
  def func(implicit t: T[A]) = t.getType
}
```

When I try to typify `C[A]` I get an error

```
val list: List[Int] = 1 :: 2 :: Nil

val result =
  list match {
    case list: List[t] => new C[t] //type parameter 't'
  }

result.func //Error: could not find implicit value for parameter t: T[t]
```

What is wrong in this case of the usage of a type parameter in the pattern matching?

Updated
Another simple example:

```
val array =
    List[Int](1, 2, 3, 4) match {
      case l: List[a] => scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[a]()
    }

  array += 1
```

Error: `type mismatch; found: Int(1), required: a array += 1`

Comment: After the edit I don't think this is a duplicate cc @Yuval